# ESXi 6.0 DCUI frozen, host is in not responding state

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

One of the ESXi hosts lost connection and entered an unresponsive state, and all of its VMs are disconnected in vSphere. However, I can RDP into the VMs, and can ping them and the host as well. SSH is not enabled on the host, so I had to physically check on it. On the DCUI I could log in, but nothing after that. F2 and F12 are not responding, but pressing NumLock works, so it's not a keyboard or BIOS update.

After a few hours I checked it again, and it got through to the system customization window (F2).  I'm thinking about maybe the management agents are stopped? Or perhaps it's a hardware issue?

I really have no idea what is the cause of it, for I've never seen anything like this and I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to VMware.

Any help or advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This can be many factors, I suggest the following articles:

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1017135

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003409

Or try reboot the host via command prompt (IP-KVM) or via resetting the power after business hours. (not preferred)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it up and running again by remotely shutting down all VMs and doing a hard reset on the host at night.
I enabled SSH and powered on the VMs one by one.

This is not a final solution, so I'll update ESXI 6.0 to 6.7 soon.